# export to csv file time series with R

Tags: r, time-series

I have done  time series forecasting using `auto.arima` model selection, and now I would like to export results as a data frame (csv file)  with appropriate index like this :
Date forecast

this an example of my forecast:

arimaMod

```
Forecasts:
      Point Forecast    Lo 80     Hi 80    Lo 95     Hi 95
16375       7237.749 6185.481  8290.017 5628.444  8847.054
16376       7281.550 6107.853  8455.247 5486.536  9076.565
16377       8454.528 7223.022  9686.035 6571.102 10337.955
16378       9185.438 7953.734 10417.143 7301.709 11069.168
16379       9319.427 8073.644 10565.211 7414.166 11224.689
16380       8874.671 7628.500 10120.843 6968.817 10780.526
```

How can I transform 16375 to Date {(as.Date(16375)="2014-11-01"} and a get a data frame in the appropriate format.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: any response will be appricated

Comment: What have you already tried? Why did it not work? Is there an origin for the points?

Comment: @Heroka , thanks for your reply,consedering that i have Forecasts
how can I export a csv file like this:


                     date                forecast          lo95          HI95
                    2014-11-01   7237.749           5628.444   8847.054

Comment: just do `write.csv`? I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: @Heroka ,the question is: before write it with write.csv how can i transforme the column which contain(16375,...16380) to date format

Comment: class(Forecasts):[1] "forecast"

Comment: @max You are incredibly impatient and have no right to spam my email accounts to *alert* me to your problems, especially so as less than an hour had elapsed after you asked your question.

Comment: @GavinSimpson ,thanks for reply ,I'm sorry for the inconvenience .i'have spent all night searching for the solution but i have not found it, have you any idea please? thanks in advance

Comment: so how can i get export the result into data frame with the appropriate date like this                       :
                        Point Forecast    
                2014-11-01       7237.749 
                2014-11-02       7281.550

Answer (score 0):

To transform a numeric to Date use:

```
    as.Date(16375,origin='1970-01-01')
[1] "2014-11-01”
```

So in your case assuming a data frame 'df' and a date column ‘Point'

```
df$Point <- as.Date(df$Point, origin='1970-01-01’)
```

will convert to date format and you can write ‘df' to a file using `‘write.table’` or `'write.csv’` as mentioned by Heroka.

update:

Max, looking at your comment and the result of the 'str' function I can see that there is no variable in your data frame that you can convert to a date! What you should do is convert the `row names` to a date like so:

```
df$date <- as.Date(as.numeric(rownames(df), origin='1970-01-01'))
```

this will add a new column to your data frame with the row names converted to valid dates.

a more explicit example:

```
> df <- data.frame(name=LETTERS[1:3],value=1:3)
> df
  name value
1    A     1
2    B     2
3    C     3

> df$date <- as.Date(as.numeric(rownames(df), origin='1970-01-01'))
> df
  name value       date
1    A     1 1970-01-02
2    B     2 1970-01-03
3    C     3 1970-01-04
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: hvollmeier,thanks for your reply i have tested it but does not work,this is the error:> df$Point <- as.Date(df$Point, origin="1970-01-01")
Error in as.Date.default(df$Point, origin = "1970-01-01") : 
  do not know how to convert 'df$Point' to class “Date”           consedring that the class(df) return "forecast",  any proposition ? thanks

Comment: if i convert the df to data frame like this :df=as.data.frame(df) and after i make  df$Point <- as.Date(df$Point, origin='1970-01-01’) it works but it givis me a false dates :( any idea ?

Comment: Check the type of the variable "Point" with "str" and make sure that it's numeric. If it's a factor or  character convert it before applying the "as.Date" function.

Comment: my df at the first is not a data frame , it a rusult of model forecasting so class(df)='forecast'   it is in the same shape like "forecasts" ( (see above)my first comment) .  names(df): 1] "method"    "model"     "level"     "mean"      "lower"     "upper"     "x"         "xname"    
 [9] "fitted"    "residuals"

Comment: df=as.data.frame(df) ,> str(df)
'data.frame': 60 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Point Forecast: num  7238 7282 8455 9185 9319 ...
 $ Lo 80         : num  6185 6108 7223 7954 8074 ...
 $ Hi 80         : num  8290 8455 9686 10417 10565 ...
 $ Lo 95         : num  5628 5487 6571 7302 7414 ...
 $ Hi 95         : num  8847 9077 10338 11069 11225 ...